# Horizontal scrollbar not working when browser width is re-sized?

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have a div and within that i have divs with images in. what i want is for all the images to display but when the browser width is re-sized(smaller) for an automatic horizontal scrollbar to appear rather than the images stacking up below. I'm trying to create this but its not working. Any help??

```
<div style="height:80px;width:auto;border:1px solid red;white-space:nowrap;overflow-y:hidden;-ms-overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll;-ms-overflow-x:scroll;">
  <div style="height:60px;width:90px;display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" >
      <img style="max-height:60px;height:auto;max-width:90px;width:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:5px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img1.png"  />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:60px;width:90px;display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" >
      <img style="max-height:60px;height:auto;max-width:90px;width:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:5px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img1.png"  />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:60px;width:90px;display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" >
      <img style="max-height:60px;height:auto;max-width:90px;width:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:5px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img1.png"  />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:60px;width:90px;display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" >
      <img style="max-height:60px;height:auto;max-width:90px;width:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:5px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img1.png"  />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div style="height:60px;width:90px;display:inline-block;">
    <a href="#" >
      <img style="max-height:60px;height:auto;max-width:90px;width:auto;margin:0 auto;padding:5px;display:inline-block;vertical-align:middle;" src="img1.png"  />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It didn't work on Firefox ONLY. For Firefox I had to set the 'fieldset' tag style to be 'display:table-column;'. As my main div was inside  tags which was in another div with a class of 'container' (Bootstrap), the fieldset kept taking the container width.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work for me as expected. https://fiddle.jshell.net/ph110293/goetup62/

Comment: It's still not working for me. I'm using bootstrap classes for responsiveness. It may be that the style are conflicting. Your example works but mine just does not.

Comment: I'm sorry let me re-enter the code its a bit different.

Comment: This code doesn't have any bootstrap classes inside html elements. It shouldn't cause any conflict.

Comment: I have update fiddle's link. It's working with your new code.

Comment: the code is not updated. I have 1 big div and within that [div > a > img]